# How to calculate the increased likelihood of drawing a type of item from a supply of mixed item types after adding more of a specific items type?

Tags: likelihood, games, odds

There is a board game, [The Castles of Burgundy](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/84876/castles-burgundy), which has a supply of 40 "black market" tiles, of which 16 are beige, 8 green, 2 gray, 6 blue, 6 yellow, and 2 burgundy.

The game takes place over five phases. Each phase, 4/6/8 tiles are randomly selected from these tiles in 2/3/4 player games. In total, players will see 20/30/40 of the tiles in 2/3/4 player games.

One of the game's expansions adds two more beige tiles, for a new total of 42 tiles, of which 18 beige, 8 green, 2 gray, 6 blue, 6 yellow, and 2 burgundy.

**How do I calculate the increased likelihood at each player count that the two new beige tiles will be drawn?** These tiles are used to fill areas on a player's game board, and I'd like to be able to say, "it's X percent more likely" that players will actually see more beige tiles than other tiles to see how balanced or unbalanced it might be to add these tiles.

Other expansions also add an additional beige tile, two yellow tiles, and a green tile, so I'd like to be able to know how to calculate this so I can solve for those situations, too.